# how to show progress bar for file upload using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

i am using this directive

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            console.log(modelSetter)
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and my service was

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

in my controller

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
```

my question is how to show progress bar while uploading image to url my JSfiddle URl https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, working fine for me

```
this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl, progressCB) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        uploadEventHandlers: {
            progress: progressCB
        }
    })
        .success(function () {
        })
        .error(function () {
        });
}

$scope.uploadFile = function () {
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ');
    console.dir(file);
    var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, , function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var progressBar = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            console.log(progressBar);
            //here you will get progress, you can use this to show progress
        }
    });
};
```

what progressCB presents

Comment: getting type error a is not a function  

`TypeError: a is not a function`

Comment: @User_3535 in service or controller?

Comment: @User_3535 I think you are messing with Dependency injection, pls check that

Comment: ., thankz it worked ., i implemented in one controller and checking in other controller ., bad me .,

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would say. Use this [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) directive. It has these features inbuilt.

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'upload/url',
            data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
        });
    };
```

see the demo [here](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Nprogress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6u154pju/)

```
NProgress.start()

NProgress.done()
```